# Passing value from a dropdown box in sinatra & ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra

It looks like for whatever reason sinatra will not recognize the "code" I use is my get "/library" do I tried putting it into a string but to no avail. taking out the quotation marks makes them an uninitialized method. Help is greatly appreciated!

```
  require 'sinatra'
  require 'sinatra/reloader'
  require 'data_mapper'

  enable :sessions

  DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/project3.db")

  class Code
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :language, String
  property :purpose, String
  property :code_snippet, Text

end

DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

get "/snippet" do
  erb :snippet, layout: :project3_template
end

post "/snippet" do
  Code.create params
  redirect to ("/library")
end

get "/library" do
  @html = Code.all(language: HTML)
  @css = Code.all(language: CSS)
  @javascript = Code.all(language: Javascript)
  @ruby = Code.all(language: Ruby)
  erb :library, layout: :project3_template
end

get "/library/:id" do
  @code = Code.get :id
  erb :code_id, layout: :project3_template
end
```

my erb page

```
<h1>Code Library</h1>

<h2>HTML</h2>
 <%= @html.each do |code| %>
   <a href="/library/<%= code.id %>"><%= code.purpose %></a>
 <hr>
<%= end %>

<h2>CSS</h2>
 <%= @css.each do |code| %>
   <a href="/library/<%= code.id %>"><%= code.purpose %></a>
 <hr>
<%= end %>

<h2>Javascript</h2>
 <%= @javascript.each do |code| %>
   <a href="/library/<%= code.id %>"><%= code.purpose %></a>
 <hr>
<%= end %>

<h2>Ruby</h2>
 <%= @ruby.each do |code| %>
  <a href="/library/<%= code.id %>"><%= code.purpose %></a>
 <hr>
<%= end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the view like this

```
erb :project3_template
```

where project3_template would be project3_template.erb in your views folder

Your @ class variables should be visible in the view, regular variables you can pass like below, `:name` in this sample is what if passed by the client through a GET or POST, these are all present in the params array. You could also pass the whole params array.

```
erb :project3_template, :locals => {:name => params[:name]}
```

See https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra#accessing-variables-in-templates

Your view has one serious issue: the use of `<%%>` and `<%=variable%>`

`<%%>` is for embedding Ruby code that has to be executed
`<%=variable%>` is for embedding the contents of a variable.
In your case you need do do the following

```
<%@html.each do |code|%>
   <a href="/library/<%= code.id %>"><%= code.purpose %></a>
 <hr>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!